# Sending a location in Telegram with GPS points with telethon

Tags: python, gps, maps, telegram, telethon

I have a GPS file and I want to display it interactively in Telegram.

By searching, I found this code that only sends a simple map. (I need to display GPS points)

```
from telethon.tl import types, functions
geoPoint = types.InputGeoPoint(gps_x, gps_y)
async with bot.action(channel, 'location') as action:
   await bot.send_file(channel, types.InputMediaGeoPoint(geoPoint))
```

Also, I use gpxplotter's package, which produces an HMTL file for me, but I don't know how to display it in Telegram.

[image: html file generated by gpxplotter's library]

Thanks.

Comment: how can you do it using official application: https://t.me/c/1109500936/78413 ?

Answer (score 0):

When looking at how it is implemented in Telegram itself, a user receives something like an image with a link that leads to Google Maps with the desired coordinates. In your case, you can send an image and a link to your HTML, which needs to be made publicly accessible (for example, on hosting or using various cloud services).